# How to make JFileChooser not appearing along with the form it belongs?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Based on this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-filechooser.html) I have added a JFileChooser in my form , but it appears when the form is loaded for the first time along with the form.
Any ideas on how to fix that?
Here is the code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package nysemarketpick;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/**
 *
 * @author skiabox
 */
public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainForm
     */
    public MainForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        fileChooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        Exit = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Nyse Stock Pick");
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
        mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 1082, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 621, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        Open.setText("Open");
        Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                OpenActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(Open);

        Exit.setText(" Exit");
        Exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ExitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(Exit);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Options");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        jMenu3.setText("Tools");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

        jMenu4.setText("Help");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu4);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(mainPanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(0, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(fileChooser, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(0, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(mainPanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(43, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .add(0, 135, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(fileChooser, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(0, 135, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            //What to do with the file
            PriceVolumeChart chart = new PriceVolumeChart(file.getName());
            mainPanel = chart.myPanel;

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
        }
    }                                    

    private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem Exit;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
    private javax.swing.JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Much of this code is generated from netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix my problem by adding the JFileChooser to Other Components node in the Navigator Window of Netabens (v7.1.2), instead of adding it to the JForm.
Maybe the tutorial is old , and it may work only in older netbeans versions.